# C# - How not make WPF UI Freeze while elaborating

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a button that after I click it send a lot of data in a remote database with a loop, but during this operation whole wpf UI is freezing. My goal is to make the loader work while it is processing everything with the database.
My button code:

```
 private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pb_loader.IsIndeterminate = true; //<- it has to start to make animation

            IEmailService emailService = new EmailService();
            IUserQueryService emailQueryService = new UserQueryService();
            var idIniziale = int.Parse(txtIdIniziale.Text);
            var idFinale = int.Parse(txtIdFinale.Text);
            var n = idFinale - idIniziale;
            string mail = "";
            for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
            {
                mail = txtMail.Text + idIniziale + "@mail.local";
                var exist = emailQueryService.CheckUserExist(mail); //<- db operation method
                if (exist == false)
                {
                   var lastUniqueId = emailQueryService.GetLastUniqueId();//<- db operation method
                   lastUniqueId = lastUniqueId + 1;
                   var idUtente = emailService.SalvaUtente(mail, lastUniqueId); //<- db operation method
                   emailService.AssegnaReferente(idUtente, txtMail.Text);//<- db operation method
                   emailService.AssegnaRuoli(idUtente); //<- db operation method

                }
                idIniziale++;
            }
            pb_loader.IsIndeterminate = false; //<- it has to end animation of loading
        }
```

Comment: You should bind to a [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=net-5.0) implementation and open a thread for the operation/s by loading it with an async method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One straighforward approach for running a background operation in an event handler is to declare the event handler `async` and run and `await` a Task:

```
private async void btn_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // prevent click while operation in progress
     btn_Start.IsEnabled = false;

     pb_loader.IsIndeterminate = true;

     // access UI elements before running the Task
     var mail = txtMail.Text + idIniziale + "@mail.local";
     ...

     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         // perform background operation
         // use local variables "mail" etc. here
     });

     pb_loader.IsIndeterminate = false;

     btn_Start.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
    System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
    System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text.get()
    OfficineEmail.MainWindow.btn_Start_Click.AnonymousMethod__4_0() in MainWindow
... It says that he can't call this thread as it is property of another thread

Comment: See the edit. You have to access UI elements outside the Task action. If that is not possible, use Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: yea the edit worked thanks, didn't think about that